# How to get UserName in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net

Can I catch username in `Application_AuthenticateRequest` event or any?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can starting with the `HttpContext.Current.User`

Answer (score 2):

I use `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity`

Answer (score 0):

If the application pool pipeline mode is set to classic, then you can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.User;
```